# A script broken when linked with dynamic import instead of plain <script> tag

Tags: javascript, import, es6-modules

I have a homemade audio player that works perfectly on my website when linked to the page via regular `script` tag:

```html
<head>
  …
  <script type="application/javascript" src="/static/js/player.js"></script>
</head>
```

The script itself is written in plain JS without any libraries, frameworks, etc. [Here is the demo of how it works](http://dev.chebykin.ru/player/01/): you press the triangle, the player starts to play; there’s nothing special here. (It may not work in some old browsers, but this doesn’t matter now.)

However, the player got broken if I link it with dynamic import (in browsers that support this kind of import). In HTML, another script `index.js` is linked instead of `player.js`, and this `index.js` imports `player.js`:

```js
// index.js
console.log('index.js is running…');
import('/static/js/player.js');
```

[Here is the second demo of this version](http://dev.chebykin.ru/player/02/), tested in Chrome on Windows and Safari on macOS, all browsers and OS’s being of latest versions at the moment of this post.

`player.js` seems to be loading and executing. When I include `console.log()`s into it, it outputs them exactly where I expect; I also didn’t find any runtime difference from the previous version with the debugger in Dev Tools.

But the audio player is not working in this case. If you press the triangle, then, instead of launching the player, you get only a direct link to the MP3 file. Initially, it was the intended behavior when the script wasn’t loaded or was broken; but I cannot figure out what exactly breaks in this case.

The script `player.js` is exactly the same in both cases; the only difference is adding dynamic import in the second case. Please help me find what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put your js files on the headers, that's where magic happen.
If you read your **player.js** file, you see your player replies on **DOMContentLoaded**

```
new Effect({  // container
behavior: `
  $window
    DOMContentLoaded
      _.init
`,
prop
....
```

On your first example, Your website basically stops loading until **player.js** loaded because you put it on header, **player.js** able to bind event to **DOMContentLoaded**. Then, after all initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, event **DOMContentLoaded** fired, and your Player able to start

On your second example, http://dev.chebykin.ru/player/02/. The event **DOMContentLoaded** will be fired after script on file **player.js** because you loaded file though import command. Even Though your script still able to bind event **DOMContentLoaded**, but it already fired, so it got no effect

You may simple try to manual trigger event again on Chrome console, and will see your player working fine by using this script

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('DOMContentLoaded'))
```

Answer (score 0):

As old versions of JS had no import but since 2015 (ES6), JS has had the ES6 modules standard to import modules in NodeJS.

I would try one of this two different approach to make it work:

**1 -** Loading dynamically with script tags from the index.js file, like:

*Index.js:*

```
function dynamicallyLoadScript(jsFilePath) {
    var js = document.createElement("script");

    js.type = "text/javascript";
    js.src = jsFilePath;

    document.body.appendChild(js);
    //or: document.head.appendChild(script); 
}

dynamicallyLoadScript("/static/js/player.js");
```

**2 -** Or use the new ES6 modules import (remember to store the *player* file with the *mjs* extension!):

```
<script type="module">
  import { player } from './static/js/player.mjs';
  player();
</script>
```

*Player.mjs:*

```
export function player() {
   //Your code here
}
```

Also, you could use some tools like Babel or Webpack if you need older browsers compatibility. You could find more info here: [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Hope it helps!

Comment: I asked not for a general method to connect a JS file to the webpage; I think I know these methods pretty well. My question was why this particular script is working perfectly when linked via regular `script` tag, but doesn’t work as intended when linked via dynamic `import`. In the latter case, the script is loaded and executed (at least partially), what you can see in console; so the problem seems not to be with the method of file linking, but somewhere else. Perharps the event handlers are registered different depending on this method, or something else—I cannot figure out.